# How do you inspect the properties and methods of a web3 object in web3.py?

Tags: web3.py

How do you inspect the properties and methods of a web3 object in web3.py?

In Node.js, if I type in the name of my web3 instance and press enter, the object is printed in the console. I am able to see all properties. However, when I do the same in a python3 console, the following is returned in the console `<web3.main.Web3 object at 0x10d563bd0>`.

How can I see everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you inspect the properties and methods of any other object in Python.

For example, you can do this via `print(dir(web3))`.